# Horizontal Scrolling Div without content shifting down

Tags: html, css

I need to create a div of fixed height and 100% width. The contents of the div are a series of images (just `img` tags).

When I resize the window smaller than the overall width of the images, the last image in the list shifts/flows down and to the left, underneath the first image.

How do I keep the images from shifting/flowing to the next line and keep them all on one line so that the user is forced to scroll the div horizontally to see the rest of the images?

Here is a jsfiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnWXj/2/

Comment: what is your current code? can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`white-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) CSS property to the `div` and give it a `nowrap` value.

Show in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnWXj/4/). (Your original, plus I added the `overflow-y` property.)

CSS used:

```
div {
    height: 120px;
    background: #666;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}​
```

Comment: Ah white-space... haven't used that forever. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to Float all the images in the left.

In css use Postion Absolute for all images and then Float all the images to the left.

Something like

```
float:left;
position: absolute;
```

use these on the img tag

**this is off the top of my head has not tried it yet. So sorry if I am wrong.**